# How to create a Drawable from byte[] ? (Android)

Tags: android, arrays, type-conversion, drawable

I have an array of bytes and I need to convert it into a Android Drawable. How can I perform this conversion?

Here is what i tried but without success:

```
byte[] b = getByteArray();
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
Drawable drw = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "articleImage");
```

drw is always null!

EDIT:

My byte[] was actually corrupted/incomplete, that was the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that `b` contains meaningful data?

Comment: your byte[] is corrupted, probably from the useless conversion to a string, which is not idempotent if you are changing encoding in the middle of it.

Answer (score 39):

If your `byte[] b` is contains imagedata then you can also try this,

```
 Drawable image = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length));
```

**EDIT**

BitmapDrawable constructor without Resources is now deprecated, So use this instead:

```
Drawable image = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length));
```

Try this and let me know what happen,

Comment: It is not returning null anymore, it is returning a drawable object, but no picture is shown when I print it in the screen. I actually have a Blob in a database, I convert it to String, then to byte[], then to Drawable. It will be a pain to figure out where the error may be.

Comment: and what about if your use direct byte array to create drawable without it converting to string..?

Comment: And also store byte array directly in sqlite db as blob type, try this, let see what happening...

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a Drawable ? If Bitmap can fit, then :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```